I have a problem with the ListView.Builder on Flutter
I would like to add one more item to the list. I know the item goes to the list, but it doesn't give me a preview on the first screen.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(BytebankApp());
class BytebankApp extends StatelessWidget {
  BytebankApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ListaTransferencias(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormularioTransferencia extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _controladorCampoNumeroConta =
      TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _controladorCampoValor = TextEditingController();

  FormularioTransferencia({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Criando Transferência'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Editor(
              controlador: _controladorCampoNumeroConta,
              rotulo: 'Numero da conta',
              dica: '0000',
            ),
            Editor(
              controlador: _controladorCampoValor,
              rotulo: 'Valor',
              dica: '0.00',
              icone: Icons.monetization_on,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => _criaTransferencia(context),
              child: Text('Confirmar'),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  void _criaTransferencia(BuildContext context) {
    final int? numeroConta = int.tryParse(_controladorCampoNumeroConta.text);
    final double? valor = double.tryParse(_controladorCampoValor.text);
    if (numeroConta != null && valor != null) {
      final transferenciaCriada = Transferencia(valor, numeroConta);
      debugPrint('Criando transferencia');
      debugPrint('$transferenciaCriada');
      Navigator.pop(context, transferenciaCriada);
    }
  }
}

class Editor extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController controlador;
  final String rotulo;
  final String dica;
  final IconData? icone;

  Editor(
      {super.key,
      required this.controlador,
      required this.rotulo,
      required this.dica,
      this.icone});

//...
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: TextField(
        controller: controlador,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          icon: icone != null ? Icon(icone) : null,
          labelText: rotulo,
          hintText: dica,
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ListaTransferencias extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Transferencia> _transferencias = <Transferencia> [];
  @override

  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ListaTransferenciasState();
  }
}

class ListaTransferenciasState extends State<ListaTransferencias> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int tamanho = widget._transferencias.length;
    debugPrint('Tamanho: $tamanho');
    widget._transferencias.add(Transferencia(200.0, 2000));
    tamanho++;
    debugPrint('Tamanho: $tamanho');
    widget._transferencias.add(Transferencia(300.0, 3000));
    tamanho++;
    debugPrint('Tamanho: $tamanho');
    widget._transferencias.add(Transferencia(400.0, 4000));
    tamanho++;
    debugPrint('Tamanho: $tamanho');
    widget._transferencias.add(Transferencia(500.0, 5000));
    tamanho++;
    debugPrint('Tamanho: $tamanho');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Transferências'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: tamanho,
        itemBuilder: (context, indice) {
          final transferencia = widget._transferencias[indice];
          return ItemTransferencia(transferencia);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          final Future<Transferencia?> future =
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
            return FormularioTransferencia();
          }));
          future.then((transferenciaRecebida) {
            debugPrint('chegou no then do future');
            debugPrint('$transferenciaRecebida');
            debugPrint('$tamanho');
            widget._transferencias.add(transferenciaRecebida!);
            Transferencia confere = widget._transferencias[tamanho];
            tamanho++;
            debugPrint('$confere');
            debugPrint('$tamanho');
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ItemTransferencia extends StatelessWidget {
  final Transferencia _transferencia;

  ItemTransferencia(this._transferencia, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        child: ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
      title: Text(_transferencia.valor.toString()),
      subtitle: Text(_transferencia.numeroConta.toString()),
    ));
  }
}

class Transferencia {
  final double valor;
  final int numeroConta;

  Transferencia(this.valor, this.numeroConta);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Transferencia{valor: $valor, numeroConta: $numeroConta}';
  }
}

I don't know if it's a Dart/Flutter syntax error, but I've already tried adding them directly to the list index and I've already checked that the items are included in the list because they are printed in debugPrint

I solved this. It was just the lack of setState() when returning from then.

I think you didn't implemented the abstract createState method of statefulWidget class correctly.
Here's what you have done:
class ListaTransferencias extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Transferencia> _transferencias = <Transferencia> [];
  @override

  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ListaTransferenciasState();
  }
}

Fix
class ListaTransferencias extends StatefulWidget {
  
  @override
  State<ListaTransferencias> createState()=> ListaTransferenciasState();
  
}

createState method should return the state of the widget that's being built.
For more info see statefulWidget
